# get the request time and ip address

Tags: php

```
$myFile = "Test.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r+') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']);
fclose($fh);
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

I need to send this page to a person and get back his IP and connection date and time
as you can see I know how to get the IP and save it to the test file but I also need to know when this IP connect to the page(date and time).

How I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` (or `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT']` if you have PHP 5.4.0 and above).

Answer (score 0):

use [`date();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function to capture date and time

example:

```
echo date('d.m.Y h:i:s');
```

In your case:

```
$myFile = "Test.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a+') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
fwrite($fh, date('d.m.Y h:i:s').PHP_EOL); 
fclose($fh);
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'<br />';
echo date('d.m.Y h:i:s');
```

*Notice* `a+` *paramether in fopen function.*